# Adding all the values in a map in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

How to add all the values of a map to have the total of 14000?

```
Map<String, int> salary = {
    "user1": 4000,
    "user2": 4000,
    "user3": 3000,
    "user4": 3000,        
  };
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, you just care about the values of this map, not care about the keys, so we work on the values by this:

```
var values = salary.values;
```

And we can use reduce to combine all the values with sum operator:

```
var values = salary.values;
var result = values.reduce((sum, element) => sum + element);
print(result);
```

You can reference some basic of List & Map here:

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List-class.html
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/Map-class.html

Comment: Its correct... But please consider .fold() as it can be used in more cases than .reduce(). Also its safer with list that might present an empty value from a returning http call