# Finding the sum of all values in a List of maps in Flutter

Tags: flutter

So I have a List of Maps of two dynamic variables.

```
 [{Title: product 1, Item Score: 87.3, Characters: 72, Image Count: 6},

 {Title: product 2, Item Score: 85.1, Characters: 56, Image Count: 2}]
```

How would I add up all of them item scores? There are more items than this in the full file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that, you need to store the value in some variable, you can simply use [List.forEach((element){ })](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/forEach.html)

Advantage, you can iterate over as many data as you can, and then store the value

```
void main(){
  var data = [{"Title": "product 1", "Item Score": 87.3, "Characters": 72, "Image Count": 6}, {"Title": "product 2", "Item Score": 85.1, "Characters": 56, "Image Count": 2}];
  
  double totalScores = 0.0;
  // looping over data array
  data.forEach((item){
    //getting the key direectly from the name of the key
    totalScores += item["Item Score"];
  });
 
  print(totalScores); // OUTPUT ==> 172.39999999999998
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is the exact answer I was looking for. Would there be an easy way to count the total number of Item Scores also without adding a counter variable in there?

Comment: Check this out @borderal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52058249/5362583

Answer (score 7):

I would look at `fold` in the standard library https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/fold.html.

With `fold`, you iterate over the list of maps, and the first argument is your starting value. In the case of sum, this would be 0. Your inner function in the fold takes 2 arguments, the current accumlation(sum), and the item in your list that is currently being iterated over.

E.g.:

```
const itemScores = [{'itemScore': 1}, {'itemScore': 2}, {'itemScore': 44}];
  var sum = itemScores.fold(0, (i, el){
    return i + el['itemScore'];
  });
```

Where i is the current value of the accumulator, and el is the current item in the list being iterated over.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,7],[8,9,10],[14,15,19]];
    int stairsIn203(List<List<int>> arr) {
      // your code here
      int _a = 0 ;
      List _b = [];
      for(List i in arr){
        _b += i;
      }
      _a = _b.reduce((value, element) => value + element) * 20;
      return _a;
    }

Or

int stairsIn20(List<List<int>> arr) => arr.expand((e) => e).reduce((v, e) => v + e) * 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = [{Title: product 1, Item Score: 87.3, Characters: 72, Image 
Count: 6}, {Title: product 2, Item Score: 85.1, Characters: 56, Image 
Count: 2}]].reduce((item1, item2) => item1["Item Score"] +item2["Item 
Score"]);
```